# Symfony event subscriber specific path

Tags: symfony, events, event-handling

I'm working on a project and basically it's one project containing 2 areas: the main frontend (which is for customers mainly) and the backend (which is for employees to manage things, this is accessible through `/admin`). Now, for both the frontend and backend we have several event subscribers.

The issue is, every subscriber has one `KernelEvents::CONTROLLER` function. But regardless of the controller, regardless of "sub controllers" etc., all of those get executed always.

My question is, is it possible to bind EventSubscribers to a specific path, set of controllers or something, so that not all event subscribers with `KernelEvents::CONTROLLER` get called every time anybody goes on the website? I know I can build in if statements, but still DI will be done for all those event subscribers and they will be called even if that specific one isn't necessary for the route.

(I don't have much better to show, I tried searching for this but I didn't get any answer or maybe I didn't understand the documentation. As for the code:

```php
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return [
        KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => 'onControllerEvent'
    ];
}
```

This is basically what I have in multiple event subscribers, where of course the injected modules in the constructor and the function inside `onControllerEvent` function different is, hopefully this cleared up any questions)

Comment: Basically no.  All controller event listeners are going to be fired.  Unless you have some real heavy dependencies then I would not worry about it.  Probably not going to notice any performance hits.  As bin/console debug:event-dispatcher shows, there are already quite a few listeners.  If it really impacted performance then you could define your own events and have one controller event listener fire off your custom events as needed.

Comment: @Cerad I will benchmark it a bit and look into it, taking your comment in consideration. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All listeners/subscribers for the `KernelEvents::CONTROLLER` event receive a `ControllerEvent` object, which contains the `Request` object (see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.4/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php#L139). Through the `Request` object you can differentiate based on paths in your listeners/subscribers. That is probably not best practice, but you could.

All listeners/subscribers will however still fire, as @Cerad said. But you can abort the processing of the event, before performance-relevant code is executed.